# asp.net - Access Many-to-Many relationship properties

Tags: c#, ssms, relationship

I am doing an exercise and part of it requires me to do a button that changes the role of a user from `User` to `subbed user`. The tables that I am using are `Roles (Id, Title)` and `Users (Id, name, etc, )` and they are connected via a many-to-many relationship, therefore I tried accessing the property title per user using the line `u.Roles.FirstOrDefault().Title`, as follows:

```
public void ChangeRoleFromUserToSubscribedUser(User u)
{
    u.Roles.FirstOrDefault().Title = "Subscribed User";

    Entity.SaveChanges();
}
```

and the then method that gets the user:

```
public ActionResult Change(string email)
{
    UsersRepository ur = new UsersRepository();
    var user = ur.GetUser().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);

    ur.ChangeRoleFromUserToSubscribedUser(user);
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

Now, I tried to change the name of a certain user (let's call him bob) and it worked, however, when I use the code above, when I press the button, the role of Bob does not change from `User` to `Subscribed user`. Instead, the title from the table `Roles` changes from `User` to `Subscribed User`.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
public void ChangeRoleFromUserToSubscribedUser(User u)
{
    var role = u.Roles.FirstOrDefault();
    role.Title = "Subscribed User";
    Entity.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Modified;

    Entity.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Updated**

You need to update `UserRoles` instead of `Roles` table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly is the variable inside the brackets "entity"? Sorry, new to this stuff..

Comment: It's `role` instead of `entity`.

Comment: I tired it that way and it resulted in the same outcome.. Instead of having the role of a user change, the role title "User" inside the Roles table changed...

Comment: The problem is that I am not accessing the role of a specific user, I am accessing the Roles Title inside the roles table

Comment: Why don't you give us your structure of class `Roles` and `User`?

Comment: Why don't you declare a table `FunctionPermission(RoleId, UserId, etc..)`

Comment: I have the table UserRoles, which is the middle table between Users and Roles, since it is a many-to-many..

Comment: We should move on chat to discuss more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205086/discussion-between-anonymous-and-rick-astley).

Comment: Yes, the same my idea, So you should provide that information to more details in your post.

Comment: Then you need to update `UserRoles` table instead of.

Answer (score 0):

The following line

```
u.Roles.FirstOrDefault().Title = "Subscribed User";
```

Is selecting the Role object assigned to the user and then changing the title of the Role to "Subscribed User".  Specifically, you are changing the Role with the title "User" to "Subscribed User" which isn't what you want.

You want to set the Role of the user to the existing entity object as follows (I'm assuming there's a RoleRepository that isn't defined):

```
var newRole= new RoleRepository().GetRole("Subscribed User");
var oldRole = u.Roles.First(x => x.Title == "User");
u.Roles.Remove(oldRole);
u.Roles.Add(newRole);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I go about the GetRole method please? Because I still do not know how I am going to access the role of a selected user field.

Comment: That depends on how you are accessing the Roles entities.  If you are using a repository design you can create a RoleRepository similarly to the UserRepository you already have, and then access the Roles entities table directly and do a search on the specific role you want (in this case "Subscribed User").